# Compressing strings with a limited set of characters, then decompressing in JS

Tags: javascript, performance, compression

Suppose I have a list of strings which contain a very limited set of characters (basically, strings that match `/^[A-Za-z0-9\-]+$/`). Is there a (reasonably simple) way to compress these strings, in such a way that they can be decompressed in client-side JavaScript? I assume it should be possible to take advantage of the limited character set.

I've looked into using things like LZW and lz-string for this purpose, but this is really overkill (and these don't take advantage of the limited set of characters I'm using). Since this isn't really English text, shoco and smaz don't work well either.

My use case: I want to store a long list of HTML element/attribute/event names without inflating the size of my code by several KB.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try a simple run-length encoding for example.

Comment: I don't think that would work well (there are very few repeated letters in these lists); I'm looking more for something that would turn two characters (from a limited set) into one character (using all possible characters).